# Multiple condition for one if value

Tags: c#, .net, windows

```
public enum Waypointtype { Start, Point, End };
Waypoint currentPoint = m_ListPoints[i];
if(currentPoint.Type == (Waypointtype.Start || Waypointtype.End))
```

Hello, is there a way do this "if" like above in c#? I am bit lazy and always searching to find a way to write shorter code. Or is the only way like below?

```
if (currentPoint.Type == Waypointtype.Start || currentPoint.Type == Waypointtype.End)
```

Comment: Make an array of your wanted enums and check like this `if(myEnums.Contains(currentPoint.Type))`

Comment: What about `if(currentPoint.Type != Waypointtype.Point)`?

Comment: @Rafalon That could be dangerous if another option is added in future.

Comment: Normally, code is read way more often than that it's written and you should consider the longer variant if it is more readable. I'd even go so far and extract the condition in a method on its own `IsTerminatingWaypoint(currentPoint)`.

Comment: @Eldar of all proposed options, this one is the one that appeals me the most, but the naming is sub-optimal at best. Go with `terminatingWaypointTypes.Contains(currentPoint.Type)` and I'm in.

Comment: @PaulKertscher Of course having a meaningful name is the way to go.

Comment: @John Agreed, of course :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a shorter way than what you already have. There are two other approaches that I can think of. For example, you could use a `switch` statement:

```
switch (currentPoint.Type)
{
    case Waypointtype.Start:
    case Waypointtype.End:
        // do stuff
        break;
    default:
        // default case
        break;
}
```

Or you could use an array with contains:

```
if (new [] { Waypointtype.Start, Waypointtype.End }.Contains(currentPoint.Type))
```

In my opinion, the switch conveys intent better here.

Comment: While this can be done, it's not really less characters than the plain `if` (well the second option is, but the difference is only 5 characters) and imho both options are way less readable.

Comment: Second option is worse scenario, on every execution it instantiate and then enumerate a new array. Instead you can use `HashSet` and keep only one instance as static variable/member

Comment: @Basin You're right of course. Creating and evaluating the array in the statement takes 2.7 times the time that a static `HashSet` does. Though if it's code that isn't going to be run many times, it doesn't really matter too much. :-)

Comment: @Basin Indeed :-)

Answer (score 1):

`Flag` attribute can be right tool for the job

```
[Flags] 
public enum Waypointtype 
{ 
  Start = 1, 
  Point = 2, 
  End = 4
};
```

Notice that enumeration values should be in powers of two: 1, 2, 4, 8, and so on.

Usage

```
const Waypointtype StartOrEnd = Waypointtype.Start | Waypointtype.End;
var current = Waypointtype.Start;

if ((StartOrEnd & current) == current)
{        
    // current type is one of values from test type.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Right answer should be @Fabio's answer of using enum `Flag` attribute.

But, because we are using object-oriented programming language, we should benefit from it.

Condition uses class `Waypoint` and it's property `Type` of enum type `Waypointtype`.
So only class should know "am I of start or end type?".
By encapsulating condition within class we can provide readable name and protect class consumers from knowing implementation details.

```
// Use FlagAttribut
[Flag]
public enum WaypointType { Start = 1, Point = 2, End = 4 };

public class Waypoint
{
    private const WaypointType START_OR_END = WaypointType.Start | WaypointType.End;
    public WaypointType Type { get; set; }

    public bool IsStartOrEnd => (StartOrEnd & Type) == Type;
}
```

Usage become short, readable and reusable.

```
Waypoint currentPoint = m_ListPoints[i];

if (currentPoint.IsStartOrEnd())
{
     // do staff
}
```

Notice that we(developers) are reading code much more than writing it (80% vs 20% maybe).
So instead of writing short code, write it in the way it can be read and understood quickly.
Sometimes it can be dome by writing short code and sometimes it can be done by encapsulating short code under comprehensible structure.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an extension method for Waypoint:

```
public static class WaypointExtensions
{
    public static bool IsStartOrEnd(this Waypoint waypoint)
    {
        if (waypoint == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return (waypoint.Type == Waypointtype.Start || waypoint.Type == Waypointtype.End);
    }
}
```

And then use it like:

```
Waypoint currentPoint = m_ListPoints[i];
if(currentPoint.IsStartOrEnd())
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I agree that the logic shall be extracted to a method on its own right (anyway I disagree about the extension method for business-logic-esque code), but the OP asked for less code, which your proposed solution does not qualify for ;)

Comment: @PaulKertscher it depends, if that `if` condition is written a lot, writing a method for it once and call it multiple times could qualify for *less code*

Comment: @Rafalon This is true.